# Merge/Blend/Composite transparent webm files with a jpg/png using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I previously had generated color.webm and alpha.webm files withffmpeg using png images.
However, when I play the generated videos in my application it consumes quite some resources so I have decided to create a standard video(No alpha needed), I cannot re-record the videos as there are a lot of them at this point.

I am generating the alpha and color video using the following command `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%d.png -filter_complex "alphaextract[a]" -map 0:v -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -auto-alt-ref 0 -crf 15 -b:v 0 color.webm -map "[a]" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -auto-alt-ref 0 -crf 15 -b:v 0 alpha.webm`

I am looking to get a final video output where in alpha values are replaced with the png/jpg image, it's more like replacing the green screen with a background however in my case greenscreen is the alpha channel.

**Could any one let me know how to combine alpha.webm, color.webm with a jpg/png image without minimal or no quality loss?
.**

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. You want `color.webm` to be overlaid on a JPG image? That's straightforward. But `alpha.webm`? That's just going to be a grayscale looking video of just the extracted alpha channel. Where should the image go?

Comment: @llogan I've edited the question, Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Somewhat. I'm guessing you want `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%d.png -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -auto-alt-ref 0 -crf 15 -b:v 0 output.webm`, but I'm probably wrong.